# SOQL for getting records in QTD

Tags: soql

I am trying to fetch records using SOQL where purchase_Date is in QTD (Quarter To Date).

```
Select id from object__c where THIS_QUARTER <= purchase_Date__c AND purchase_Date__c <= TODAY
```

I think its correct but need a second opinion. Would it work or are there any cases where it will fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `=` for literal date ranges, not `<=`, which would include all previous quarters, too. TODAY is also not necessary, unless future dates are being loaded for some reason. Finally, filters must be in the form of `field operator value`, not any other combination. Here's the fixed version:

```
Select id from object__c where purchase_Date__c = THIS_QUARTER
```

OR

```
select id from object__c where purchase_date__c = this_quarter and purchase_date__c <= today
```

Comment: I made a typo about <= ....i was about to correct it. Thanks for detailed explanation